# Automatically installing Unix without using a boot image

Tags: linux, unix, installation, automation

how can I automatically install/update/configure a Unix installation without booting the installation medium? Can this be done to both a pxe booting computer and a non-pxe booting computer?

Comment: It depends on what software you're already running on the system and what distribution you would like to install or upgrade. Can you supply some more information?

Comment: Example: Using a Ubuntu system to install another Ubuntu system, and on that other Ubuntu system to install some other software such as Jitsi.

Comment: On the other system, is there any software currently installed?

Comment: We can assume the other system has an entire secondary memory(ssd/hdd) to install on and that the system doing the installation may install software to do so (I heard Vagrant might work but that may be just for virtualization).